# Check If there is any user related with the governorate before delete?

Tags: laravel

I have table called `Governorate` it has relation with `users` table.

Then I have multi delete `Governorate`, I need to say before deleting any `Governorate` check if there is any `user` has relation with `Governorate`

My multi code:

```
public function delulti(Request $request,Governorate $governorate)
{
    // here my problem 
    if($request->muti_delete->users()->count() > 0){
        session()->flash('warning','There are some Users related with this governorate');
        return redirect(route('governorate.index'));
    }

    // here everything is good and works
    if(is_array($request->muti_delete)){
        Governorate::destroy($request->muti_delete);
    }else{
        Governorate::find($request->muti_delete)->delete();
    }
    session()->flash('success', 'Deleted Governorates Successfuly');
    return redirect(route('governorate.index'));
}
```

Relation in Governorate Model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

Comment: FIrst get the reslt : `$result = Governorate::withCount('users')->whereIn('governorate_id', $request->muti_delete)->get();` 
Then get the count and then check if it is working?`$result[0]->users_count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem with `$request->muti_delete->users()->count()` is that (I assume) `$request->muti_delete` is an array of ids. So you can't do `->users()` on it.

You can use `Governoate::whereIn('id', $request->muti_delete)` to get the actual models.

---

Also you can utilise `withCount()` to return the users count.

```
public function delulti(Request $request,Governorate $governorate)
{
    $governates = Governoate::whereIn('id', $request->muti_delete)
        ->withCount('users')
        ->get();

    foreach ($governates as $governate) {
       if ($governate->users_count > 0) {
          // user exists

          session()->flash('warning','There are some Users related with this governorate');
          return redirect(route('governorate.index'));
       }
    }

    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: What is "not working"? The answer is not copy/paste and all magically works - it's to give you an idea on how to make it work yourself. `Governoate::whereIn('id', $request->muti_delete)->withCount('users')->get();` what does this return? If your relationship is setup correctly, it should return 'users_count` for each governota model in your collection. From there you can make a check if any collection item has a user count. P.S: I added an edit

Comment: Now totally understand  ! I'm sorry but your first answer was not clear:)

Comment: Yeah it is. but Can you just explain one last thing ( what is the users_count ? )

Comment: It comes from `->withCount('users')` - something like return 'count of relationship'. Take a look - [Counting Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)